# .NET Core 1.0.5 runtime offline installer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, installation, wix

I have an installer and I need to install .NET Core 1.0.5 runtime on the host machine.
So I've downloaded this .exe:

[image]

I'm running this exe as a first step of the installation process. Everything works fine as long as I'm connected to the internet. One requirement is to have a working installer without any kind of connection available. I couldn't find any .NET Core 1.0.5 offline installer, it just seem to not be available. Someone is telling me to build the offline installer on my own, I have no idea how to do it

Someone is suggesting to run the exe using the `/layout` parameter in order to create the offline installer. So I tried running the exe with the `/layout <myfolder>` parameter but it just seems to create the very same file on the `<myfolder>` folder